Summernote - how to hide internal Modal via API?
The summernote-JS Editor use and opens internally modals for inserting links, videos etc.
I want to hide e.g. the actual opened internal opened modal via Summernote-API from outside JS.
I've checked the Summernote API Docu, but didn't found an example.

I found the solution by myself.
I needed this as I wrote my own plugin with its own modal. There is an iframe in the modal. In the iframe I needed the ability to close the modal after an action.
So I´ve defined a function for hide inside the plugin:
this.hide = function () {
    ui.hideDialog(self.$dialog);
};

Now I could call this method from outside (JS-Code in iframe):
$('#mySelector').summernote('myplugin.hide');

